# How to download, unzip and import to mysql dump all via piping?

Tags: mysql, bash, ssh, pipe, gzip

Is it possible to unzip a gzipped file while it's downloading and feed it to mysql all in one go without having to create a physical file?

So far I've been able to unzip and feed it to mysql using the following:-
`gunzip < somefile.sql.gz | pv | mysql -u myself -p somedb #pv for viewing process`

The above process expects the gzipped file to be downloaded already while unzipping and feeding it to mysql.
But I haven't been able to feed to mysql  while it's unzipping and downloading simultaneously.

And if this is not possible I'd like to know the why too so as to get a peace of mind.

Comment: Sure, write a c/java/c#/python whatever app, unzip to memory. Your app would be a mysql client (via libs), and it proceeds to have fun doing whatever you want with that memory chunk against the server.

Comment: You can do it on UNIX/Linux quite easily by using named pipes. http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2156 is a simple explanation.

Comment: @Drew Sorry, I should have mentioned that I wanted it to do from shell. I'll tag as such as to not cause any confusions.

Comment: @TGray That's what I'm trying to accomplish from, as you can see from my incomplete attempt but I'm missing the download/unzip portion which seems to be the tricky part.  
Edit:- ahh..named pipes. I'll look more into it after I get home. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: in doing this in the past, I had two processes.  The first would download and start the gunzip while the second did the import side.  I confess I've never done this on a single box.  I have done this across network connections for occasions where the DB server has run out of room for a dump, so I sent it across to a different box.

Comment: @TGray yup, that's exactly what I'm going after. I am however trying it in a single box though. I'll update the post if it's a success. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've figured out. Thanks to @TGray for pointing me to the right direction.
The key was [named pipes](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/using-named-pipes-fifos-bash). Basically, you create a named pipe and start the download on that named pipes while piping that named pipe to gunzip as shown above in my post.

```
mkfifo mypipe
ssh username@server.com cat /source/file.gz > mypipe &
gunzip < mypipe | pv | mysql -uusername -ppassword dbname
```

Answer (score 1):

```
wget -qO- URL | gunzip | pv | mysql -u myself -p somedb
```

Comment: I was **just** looking for something similar. Thanks!